# In Django raw query selects all my user twice

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a raw query in my view:

```
SELECT stressz_profile.id, projekt_id, user_name_id, 
szerv01b AS szervkult01a 
FROM stressz_szervezetikultura 
INNER JOIN stressz_profile 
WHERE stressz_profile.projekt_id=1
```

I try to get the data from the db but every time it duplicates the results. It selects my users two times like on the image below and I can't figure it out why.
[image]

Comment: It means that your `v` has two rows, one with `user_name_id=7` and one with `user_name_id=1`. Since you do not perform any `JOIN` (with a condition), it will thus "multiply" the `stressz_profile` with the number of items in `stressz_szervezetikultura`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It selects my users two times like on the image below and I can't figure it out why.

Because you make an `INNER JOIN` with the `stressz_szervezetikultura`, but you never specify how these should be JOINED. It is thus will show each `stressz_profile` where the `stressz_profile.project_id=1` that many times as there are items in the `stressz_szerverzetikultura`.

You thus lack an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT stressz_profile.id, projekt_id, user_name_id, 
szerv01b AS szervkult01a 
FROM stressz_szervezetikultura
INNER JOIN stressz_profile ON …
WHERE stressz_profile.projekt_id=1
```

You thus need to fill in the join condition (the `…` part). Likely that is a condition that is about the `user_name_id`.

Answer (score 1):

because you are missing join condition:

```
SELECT stressz_profile.id, projekt_id, user_name_id, 
szerv01b AS szervkult01a 
FROM stressz_szervezetikultura  s
INNER JOIN stressz_profile p
 ON p.?? = s.?? -- the column names you are joining on
WHERE stressz_profile.projekt_id=1
```